# ErrorResponseException test java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.isEmpty()"

Tags: spring-boot, testing

When test ErroResponseException throws:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.isEmpty()" because "this.headers" is null
    at org.springframework.web.ErrorResponseException.getMessage(ErrorResponseException.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:397)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:408)
    at
```

Using Spring Boot 3.2.0

```
@WebMvcTest
class PersonControllerTest {

        @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;  
    @MockBean
    private PersonService personService;
    
    private PersonRequest personRequest;
    private PersonResponse personResponse;

        @Test
    void testGet_ShouldReturn404NotFound() throws Exception {
        String requestURI = END_POINT_PATH + "/" + TEST_UUID_1;
        doThrow(PersonNotFoundException.class).when(personService).get(TEST_UUID_1);
        mockMvc.perform(get(requestURI))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
            .andDo(print());
        verify(personService, times(1)).get(TEST_UUID_1);
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    problemdetails:
      enabled: true
```

PersonNotFound.class

```
public class PersonNotFoundException extends ErrorResponseException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public PersonNotFoundException() {      
        super(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    
}
```

PersonService.class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    
    public PersonResponse get(UUID id) {
        Person person = personRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> {
                log.info("Person with id: {} not found", id);
                return new PersonNotFoundException();
            });
        log.info("Get person with id: {}", id);
        return personToResponse(person);                
    }
}
```

PersonController.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonController {
        @GetMapping("/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<PersonResponse> get(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        PersonResponse personResponse = personService.get(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

```
doThrow(PersonNotFoundException.class).when(personService).get(TEST_UUID_1);
```

change to:

```
doThrow(new PersonNotFoundException()).when(personService).get(TEST_UUID_1);
```